# PrintWriter cmd-return equivalent

Tags: java, openoffice.org

This might be a silly a question but I have a lot of repetitive cells that I need to enter into a .ods spreadsheet.  I would like to write a simple java program to generate the data in a .txt file and then copy and paste it into the spreadsheet.

My problem is that there are multiple lines per individual cell:

First Name: Bob (cmd-return)
Last Name: Jackson

A normal return would go to the next cell.  Generating the data in the .txt file using .println() or "\n" is the equivalent of a normal return and the paste creates multiple cells.

Is there a way to create a string with the equivalent of a cmd-return?

Comment: why not use java to edit .ods?

Comment: I thought about it but it seems complex and I'm only an intermediate java student.  I'm checking it out now ... any tips?

Comment: https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Calc/API/Programming. Frankly speaking,  I never used it.  I worked on apache-poi for editing microsoft excel spread sheets.

Comment: This will depend on how ODS parses text files.  Often in files like this there is some kind of delimiter character (e.g. ") which allows whitespace in between to be part of the same row.  If you wrap your entire cell in quotes does it help?

Comment: Thanks everyone.  I ended up doing everything by hand - like a sucker.  I'll try the quotes and keep trying to find a delimiter.

Comment: @Pace: Quotes totally worked!!  If only I had a time machine...